# Newton Leibniz Theorem

Tags: leibniz-integral-rule

[image]
[image]

These both formula came under Newton Leibniz Theorem.
But i don't understand when to use  the formula '1.' and when the formula in '2'.

I was trying to solve this question. In this question we have to find the area under f(x). [image]

when i tried to do it with the formula '1' my answer didn't matched.

Comment: The case 2) is a more general case that 1), when the function under the integral depends also on $x,$ as in your exercise

Comment: You can get the correct answer using 1) if the function inside the integral is purely a function of t. For your case, you need to take $e^x$ out of the integral and apply product rule